# In android studio ，using Genymotion monitor，New project can‘t built normally

Tags: java, android, genymotion

android studio mistakes message：
Unable to establish a connection to adb.
This usually happens if you have an incompatible version of adb running already.
Try re-opening Studio after killing any existing adb daemons.
If this happens repeatedly, please file a bug at http://b.android.com including the following:
1. Output of the command: 'D:\Program Files\Android\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices'
2. Your idea.log file (Help | Show Log in Explorer)

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: 1. remove Chinesse. 2. Ask a question.

Comment: sorry, i used it first time, click wrongly, i want to modify this question, i'm looking for the solution to modify it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I has found the reason. Because there are two android sdk in different directories.  The sdk that genymotion emulator configured is not  same as android studio. So android studio can't start the adb.exe after I have started Emulator.